# JavaScript audio player

Tags: javascript, html, function, audio

I'm building a simple JavaScript audiotrack controller and I don't know what is wrong with my code. I've been searching for hours here and I found a simple code that did the job. I had to change a lot of things (due to typos or code errors) and I finally got this:

```js
var TRACKS = [
    {
        id: 0,
        nom: 'Johnny B. Goode',
        autor: 'Chuck Berry',
        src: 'src/johnnybgoode.mp3',
        any: '1955'
    },
    {
        id: 1,
        nom: 'For Your Love',
        autor: 'The Yardbirds',
        src: 'src/foryourlove.mp3',
        any: '1965'
    }
];

var songs = 2;

var Player = function () {
    "use strict";
    var currentPlaying,
        trackListPos,
        trackList,
        source,
        audio;
    
    
    this.getName = function () {
        return currentPlaying.nom;
    };
    
    this.setTrack = function (obj) {
        currentPlaying = obj;
        source.src = obj.src;
        audio.load();
        audio.play();
        return this;
    };
        
    
    this.setTrackList = function (t) {
        trackList = t;
        trackListPos = 0;
        audio = document.getElementById('myAudio');
        source = document.getElementById('audioSource');
        this.setTrack(trackList[trackListPos]);
        return this;
    };
    
    this.play = function () {
        audio.load();
        audio.play();
        return this;
    };
    
    this.stop = function () {
        audio.pause();
        audio.currentTime = 0;
        return this;
    };
    
    this.pause = function () {
        audio.pause();
    };

    this.next = function () {
        if (currentPlaying.id === (songs - 1)) {
            trackListPos = 0;
        } else {
            trackListPos += 1;
        }
        this.setTrack(trackList[trackListPos]);
    };
};

//Initialize
var reprod = new Player();
reprod.setTrackList(TRACKS).play();

function play() {
 "use strict";
 reprod.play();
 document.getElementById("Play").innerHTML = "Pause";
}

function seguent() {
    "use strict";
 reprod.next();
    document.getElementById("titol").innerHTML = "<b>T&iacute;tol:</b>";
}
```

```html
<audio id="myAudio" controls="controls">
    <source id="audioSource" src="">
    Your browser does not support the audio format.
</audio>
    <nav class="navegador" id="sidebar">
        <div class="playerwrapper">
            <div class="player">
                <p id="titol"></p>
                <p id="autor"></p>
                <p id="any"></p>
                <button type="button" onclick="seguent()">Següent</button>
                <button id="Play" type="button" onclick="play()">Play</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </nav>
```

As you can see there's a couple buttons that trigger the function play() and seguent() (which means next). And they don't seem to work.
The innerHTML that changes the Play button text doesn't work, but when I remove the "reprod.play();" line it does work and changes the button content.

Can someone explain what is exactly happening with my code?

(Sorry if the post is tedious, it's my second post here and I don't know the formatting)

Thanks for letting me know I could use a console, the errors that throws are:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'load' of null
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'src' of null
```

Comment: It's likely that calling the `reprod.play()` is throwing a JavaScript error. Check your console to see if there is an error message and share it in your question if there is.

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'src' of null
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'load' of null

Comment: On what line? What line of code is it referencing?

Comment: In function setTrack() i cannot set 'src'. In function play() i can't load.

Comment: This seems to be working, the play and seguent buttons change the text. What is the issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Observing your code, it seems the element which `setTrackList(t)` is referring to doesn't exists in the DOM. I think the element you've declared for importing this script in your HTML (the `<script>` tag) is preceeding the `<body>` with your content. You have to get sure your DOM content is loaded before calling `setTrackList(t)`, therefore you can bind the `onload` event to call this, else this function will not find the element.
**Try this:**

```
var reprod = new Player();
document.addEventListener("load", function() {
    reprod.setTrackList(TRACKS).play();
});

function play() {
    "use strict";
    reprod.play();
    document.getElementById("Play").innerHTML = "Pause";
}

function seguent() {
    "use strict";
    reprod.next();
    document.getElementById("titol").innerHTML = "<b>T&iacute;tol:</b>";
}
```

**EDIT:** Maybe I understood your problem: the context of the function which construct the class (`function Player()`) ends immediately after the calling itself, so variables are deleted. Therefore try declaring your variables in `this` context.

```
this.audio = yourValue;
```

Instead of:

```
var audio = yourValue;
```

**EDIT:** Maybe now it's working well, [try this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/em195xL3/7/).

Except the error because of missing of tracks, it seems working.

Here's the code of the fiddle:

```
var TRACKS = [
    {
        id: 0,
        nom: 'Johnny B. Goode',
        autor: 'Chuck Berry',
        src: 'src/johnnybgoode.mp3',
        any: '1955'
    },
    {
        id: 1,
        nom: 'For Your Love',
        autor: 'The Yardbirds',
        src: 'src/foryourlove.mp3',
        any: '1965'
    }
];

var songs = 2;

var Player = function () {

    this.getName = function () {
        return this.currentPlaying.nom;
    };

    this.setTrack = function (obj) {
        this.currentPlaying = obj;
        this.source.src = obj.src;
        this.audio.load();
        this.audio.play();
        return this;
    };


    this.setTrackList = function (t) {
        this.trackList = t;
        this.trackListPos = 0;
        this.audio = document.getElementById('myAudio');
        this.source = document.getElementById('audioSource');
        this.setTrack(this.trackList[this.trackListPos]);
        return this;
    };

    this.play = function () {
        //this.audio.load();
        this.audio.play();
        return this;
    };

    this.stop = function () {
        this.audio.pause();
        this.audio.currentTime = 0;
        return this;
    };

    this.pause = function () {
        this.audio.pause();
    };

    this.next = function () {
        if (this.currentPlaying.id === (songs - 1)) {
            this.trackListPos = 0;
        } else {
            this.trackListPos += 1;
        }
        this.setTrack(this.trackList[this.trackListPos]);
    };
};

//Initialize
var reprod = new Player();
if (document.getElementById("myAudio"))
  reprod.setTrackList(TRACKS).play();
else
  window.addEventListener('load', function() {
      reprod.setTrackList(TRACKS).play();
  });

window.play = function() {
    "use strict";
    reprod.play();
    document.getElementById("Play").innerHTML = "Pause";
}

window.seguent = function() {
    "use strict";
    reprod.next();
    document.getElementById("titol").innerHTML = "<b>T&iacute;tol:</b>";
}
```

And here's the HTML:

```
<audio id="myAudio" controls="controls">
    <source id="audioSource" src="">
    Your browser does not support the audio format.
</audio>
    <nav class="navegador" id="sidebar">
        <div class="playerwrapper">
            <div class="player">
                <p id="titol"></p>
                <p id="autor"></p>
                <p id="any"></p>
                <button type="button" onclick="window.seguent()">Següent</button>
                <button id="Play" type="button" onclick="window.play()">Play</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </nav>
```

Comment: I also thought about this, but it doesn't work either. 
playlist.js:60 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'load' of undefined
    at Player.play (playlist.js:60)
    at play (playlist.js:100)
    at HTMLButtonElement.onclick (index.html:18)

Comment: @Ferran Capallera Guirado, see the update in my answer: maybe your problem depends from the context of the variables.

Comment: It doesn't work either. But you might be right! Should I try declaring them as global variables?

Comment: I think that although it doesn't work either, declaring the variables in `this` is better than referring into a context that might be ended.

Comment: @Ferran Capallera Guirado, see the update in my answer: now I think your problem is solved. Sorry for all those failed attempts!

Comment: Hey man thanks for your dedication. Your event listener on load was almost the right answer. I solved it using window.addEventListener instead of document.addEventListener, working fine!

Comment: Answer update based on @Ferran Capallera Guirado 's comments.